# iPhone - adding custom MKAnnotation to MapView does not get added

Tags: iphone, ios5, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotation

for some reason I am having some problems with my custom MKAnnotation class and having it added to the map. I have also attempted to use the basic MKPointAnnotation to see if this would work, however it does not. In my function I create the Annotation, and then add it, while printing NSLogs to verify that the data is in the annotation. When it gets to printing the contents of map's annotations array, the count is 0. Does anyone know why it is not getting added to the mapView?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [map setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [map setDelegate:self];
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(30.451667, -84.268533), 16090.344, 16090.344);
    viewRegion = [map regionThatFits:viewRegion];
    [map setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
    [map setShowsUserLocation:YES];
} 

- (void)loadBuilding {
        if (buildAnnotation != nil) {
            [map removeAnnotation:buildAnnotation];
        }
        buildAnnotation = [[BuildingAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:building.getLocation withName:building.getName withAddress:building.getAddress];
        [map addAnnotation:buildAnnotation];
        [map setCenterCoordinate:buildAnnotation.coordinate animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"%@\n%@\n %f, %f", buildAnnotation.title, buildAnnotation.subtitle, buildAnnotation.coordinate.latitude, buildAnnotation.coordinate.longitude);
        NSLog(@"%i", [[map annotations] count]);
    }

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    NSLog(@"IN DELEGATE");
    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[BuildingAnnotation class]]) {

        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;        
        return annotationView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

BuildingAnnotation.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface BuildingAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c;
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c withName:(NSString*)name withAddress:(NSString*)address;
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate;

@end
```

BuildingAnnotation.m:

```
#import "BuildingAnnotation.h"

@implementation BuildingAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c {
    coordinate = c;
    title = @"Title";
    subtitle = @"Subtitle";
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c withName:(NSString*)name withAddress:(NSString*)address {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        coordinate = c;
        title = name;
        subtitle = address;
    }
    return self;
}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate {
    return coordinate;
}


@end
```

Comment: Kinda obvious question, but does map exist when you call loadBuilding? Also, NSLog is nice, but gdb might help you to dig deeper into the object structure.

Comment: Yes, the map exists, I have a the map display the user's location and the NSLog of "IN DELEGATE" does get called. I'm sorry, but in my 2 years of iOS programming I have never actually used GDB for debugging haha, could you give me an example that might help?

Comment: @Muller - you really should learn how to use GDB (or well, LLDB now!). There's a bit about it here - http://www.raywenderlich.com/10505/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-2 - but also, for this, it's pretty easy. Just set a breakpoint at the start of `loadBuilding` and check that `map` is set (hover over it and see if it's not `0x0`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what it was, all of the code was correct, however I was trying to modify data in the View Controller from another class, so I was doing `[self.storyboard instantiate...@""]` however this was creating another object and modifying that instead of modifying the original view controller. Thank you mattgalloway & Cyril!